# equirectangular rendering for Blender Internal?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

Can such frames/videos be rendered in Blender Internal as well?
If not, how indirectly?

EDIT: The below solution is great as long as you can write your own Python script and only render solid objects. When you need things like particles/hair, it won't work as those won't be reflected.

Comment: It would be possible to bake the scene onto a sphere and repeat it for every frame.

Comment: How do you do that? Repeating that for every frame could be achieved by a Python two liner I think.

Comment: Yes that is easy to do with a sphere with a shadeless material with full reflection, and a texture set tho the sphere with the resolution of the video you want to make, I assume repeating the process with python for each frame should be easy too, but that's beyond my knowledge.

Comment: You mean an inverted (normals) sphere, large enough to fill the whole volume, UV mapped accordingly? I'm not sure I understand, will I need to fetch the generated texture instead of camera render?

Comment: The sphere should be very small at the location where the camera supposed to be, and then with python you can bake the result for every frame. I can post a partial answer without the python part.

Comment: Here's a Python code for doing something every frame, I know a bit of the API: http://www.pasteall.org/60847/python  I'm not familiar with baking, if you tell me where it is in the menu I can update the code

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46891/how-to-render-an-environment-to-a-cube-map-in-cycles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First create a sphere and in edit mode select the triangular fans on the poles of the sphere and inset to very small size using <kbd>I</kbd> button and delete the triangular fans leaving very small holes on the poles.

[image]

Then unwrap the sphere using follow active quads, position and scale the UVs to fit the UV/Image editor window.
Once the sphere is unwrapped add a new texture with video resolution you want (1920x1080)

[image]

Then add a material to the sphere, enable Shadeless, Mirror and set Reflectivity to **1**

[image]

Then scale the sphere to small size and position it where the camera should be and add Subsurf modifier with at least 2 subdivisions to reduce texture distortion.

Once all the steps are finished you can use  the python script to bake the textures for each frame in a sequence.

Comment: Very odd deformations when doing this. http://i.imgur.com/fHXxry2.png  Maybe the mirror quality can and has to be changed somewhere.

Comment: Thats how it should look like but you need to make an image wider, like the video output you want.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to add, to reduce the image distortion add Subsurf modifier with at least 2 subdivisions and set it to smooth shading.

Comment: Looks better. Any chance antialiasing can be enabled for mirror texture?

Comment: @LeoErvin I'm not sure if this option exist for baking

Comment: Seems like particles aren't reflected. Not an option for me...

Comment: The above solution doesn't seem to support non-solid objects such as some particles which are not mirrored. Here's an idea: render the scene with Blender internal as 6 cube maps, then load them back again in Blender and map to a sphere or cube with inverted normals, set it to shadeless and position the camera inside it, then render just that with Cycles with the panorama/equirectangular mode.
Will need some Python scripting to automate all this and do animations.
Maybe just rendering with BI as cubemap then doing the 2n step with a 3rd party tool will be faster, however I'm not aware of such p

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure with a minor edit this script, combined with the above solution, will allow to render an equirectangular animation or frame in in Blender Internal:

```
import bpy

# remember current frame to switch back after the script is finished
current_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current

mesh = bpy.context.scene.objects.active.data

for i in range(bpy.context.scene.frame_start, bpy.context.scene.frame_end+1):
    # set current frame
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current = i

    # create an image which will store the baked data
    image = bpy.data.images.new(str(i)+'.png', bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x, bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y, alpha = 0)
    image.file_format = 'PNG'
    image.filepath = "//"+str(i)+".png"

    #set the active image for each uv:
    for uvface in mesh.uv_textures.active.data:
        uvface.image = image

    # bake
    bpy.ops.object.bake(type='COMBINED')

    # resave image with baked data
    image.save()

    print ("Frame "+str(i)+" complete")

# switch back to the frame you were on before running this code
bpy.context.scene.frame_current = current_frame
```

Currently it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\internal.blend\Text", line 22, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\modules\bpy\ops
.py", line 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: No active image found in material "Material.002" (0) for ob
ject "Sphere"
```

If someone can tell how to set the "active image" for a Material, then I think this script will run fine.