# Volume material is not rendered onto environment map

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, volumetrics, world

I have an object with a volumetric material in the scene which renders a bunch of clouds correctly from my camera. I set up a cube to create an environment map by setting up the texture as environment map and giving the cube as Viewport Object. When I hit render (after clearing all environment maps) the new environment map is calculated. All objects appear but the volumetric one.

I'm not using cycles, I'm using Blender Render engine. Also all the objects are contained in the environment map's clipping range.

Does someone have any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

[Get the blend file here](http://www.riccardostecca.net/publicfiles/VolumesAgainstEnvMapFailing.blend)

Comment: Can you [post the .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: @Mentalist done

Comment: I noticed that the material was not set to "Volume", so I changed that. Is [this](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1152/) the result you wanted?

Comment: @Mentalist I double checked, the clouds' material IS set as volume. Also I see just a blank page in your link

Comment: Sorry about the broken link. Not sure what happened - maybe Blend Exchange links can't be posted in comments, only answers? Let's ask @GiantCowFilms about this. As for your material, I think I was mistaken about the role of your cube - I thought the *cube* object was supposed to have a volume material. I'm not experienced with volume in BI, so I may not be able to figure out the problem in your .blend. As an alternative method for rendering a cube map you may find [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46891/how-to-render-an-environment-to-a-cube-map-in-cycles) helpful.

Comment: Thank you @Mentalist it's a good idea asking around. Yeah the cube is there as a placeholder for the Environment Map.