# How can I view my 3D rendered 360 pictures on gear VR?

Tags: stereoscopy

I got a gear VR with an app that lets me view pictures in 360, I have made the app able to recognice my usual 360 rendered pictures. But I have seen the same app can also show 3D 360, which means there is depth in sight in the 360 image. I have rendered a panorama picture with the stereoscopy option "spherical stereoscopy" activated. It gave me two panorama files on the output. Which are for Left and Right eye. How can I turn those into a 3D panorama file usable in Gear VR? Would love some help on this. I have gone through google about an hour with no luck on this topic, or even any information on those filetypes.

Comment: This is not a blender question, but a Samsung Gear VR question. If you can specify how to meet the requirements for Samsung Gear VR, we can see how it can be done in Blender. As a side note, owning a Samsung Gear VR, I was not able to view custom 360 3D images on my Gear VR. I resolved it by making a video of the still and viewing it in Gear VR.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful:

[How to render an environment to a Cube Map in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46891/how-to-render-an-environment-to-a-cube-map-in-cycles)

There is a section about rendering an "Equirectangular Map to Cube Map".
You can also download .blend files that come with the 3D camera and a compositing setup which seems to be pretty well documented.

I do not know of a way to view spherical images. You can view equirectangular images in the Samsung Internet Browser with some html biolerplate but the resolution really makes this a non-viable option.

Turning your scene into a Cube Map allows you to upload the file for viewing in the Oculus Photos app and it is the best solution in regards to quality.

The only downside is that you need to modify the cubemap image to follow the Oculus format which differs from what the Blender Internal mechanism expects.

Comment: Btw, I think I have read that some people got equirectangular 360 stereo images to show up correctly in Oculus Photos but so far that has not worked for me.