# Wrong equirectangular panorama

Tags: rendering, camera, panoramic

Why my panorama is wrong?

This is the cube with the camera inside.
Under the camera (and above too) 360 panorama is "shrunk":
[image]

This is the camera settings:
[image]

And this is the render result:
[image]

The scene looks like:
[image]

Blender file:

[image]

P.S. I used FSPViewer (FSoft) for view panorama render result.

Comment: I think your question was down voted, because it is not detailed enough. Can you add comment to the images you posted?

Comment: test on 2.78RC1 without problem.The pinching makes me think you used an UV sphere unwrapped.

Comment: Could you post a [.blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your blend file (in blender 2.77a) the render was ok. Then using it as environment texture in world shader and viewport showed no pinching.
[image: blender view]
The problem seems to come from FSPViewer (sphere UV mapping).
[image: FSPViewer]

EDIT:
Mapping an equirectangular texture on a UV sphere can't be done with UV unwrapping without pinching because of the tris at north and south poles. But you can use this setup:
[image: equi map UV sphere]

Comment: got it, thank you, do you know how to make spherical panorama in blender?

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for, accept it. What do you mean "spherical panorama"?

Comment: I think than found an answer - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36573/equirectangular-rendering-for-blender-internal

Comment: This is an exemple where you can use equirectangular map on a sphere, but you will get that pinching. AFAIK, the only solution I know to map an Equirectangular image on a UV sphere is using generated texture coordinates and sphere mapping on texture node.